# Create meeting in MS Outlook from SP list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, calendar, task-list, outlook

I have calendar list in SharePoint 2013 site, which I synced with my MS Outlook.
When item is created in calendar/task list, email should be sent to users from one SharePoint group, those users should receive meeting request not simple email that is sent from SP designer workflow.

I read on some blogs and sites that it is possible to schedule a meeting from SP calendar/task list in Outlook calendar via event handler, but I don't have Visual studio so that road is closed for me.
Group will have 200+ users so entering one by one user is not an option too.

What I basically need is to schedule a meeting to users from SharePoint group from calendar or task list in SharePoint.

Any advise if this is even possible from SP designer and SP2013 itself would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved it.

I created calendar list, in it I added two additional columns that are not by default visible, Attendees and Free/Busy.
After I added those two columns to list I created SPD WF2013.
There is only two actions in WF, 1st is to create WF variable and to set it's value to ID column. 2nd action is to send email to Attendees from calendar list.
Subject is Title and Body is custom text invitation to accept meeting request.
In text I added URL like this

```
Current site/_vti_bin/osswr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={ListID}&CacheControl=1&ID=[Variable ID]&using=event.ics
```

Set WF to Start on item create/manual.
After item is created Attendees receive email with the link after they click on it ics document opens. After this they can save it to their calendar with an option to set reminder however they like. If they save it, they will be presented as busy while on meeting.

*Still not resolved "problem" with Reminder. I have to somehow get inside ics document and add reminder part so it sets automatically to 15 minutes prior meeting.*